# How to add a newline after a figure?

Tags: spacing, floats

It seems that after figures there is no vertical space whatsoever. LaTeX doesn't seem to like me adding a `\\` after the figure, too.

How can I accomplish some vertical spacing after a figure?

Here's my current latex code:

```
\begin{figurehere}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=16cm]{abc.png}
    \caption{\footnotesize{my footnote 1}}
    \label{q-qg}
\end{figurehere}

\begin{figurehere}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=16cm]{def.png}
    \caption{\footnotesize{my footnote 2}}
    \label{q-qg}
\end{figurehere}

\noindent abcabc
```

This is the header of my file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Java, keywordstyle=\color{blue}, commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},escapechar=|}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow,graphicx,tabularx}
\usepackage{marvosym,textcomp,cancel,gensymb,lscape}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}  
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ucs}  %Unicode support
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % UCS' UTF-8 driver is better than the LaTeX kernel's
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  %The default font encoding only contains Latin characters
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}  %Almost European fonts/hyphenation do a better job than Computer Modern
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}  %something i found for page numbering

%hack para meter imagens e tabelas em multicol
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablehere}
  {\def\@captype{table}}
  {}

\newenvironment{figurehere}
  {\def\@captype{figure}}
  {}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{lista}{
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}{
  \end{itemize}
}

%e uns teoremazinhos$\eta$
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\title{{\bfseriesyyy}\\{\bfseries \small xxx}}
\author{\Large{xyz}\\ abcde}
\date{some date}

 %costumizar captions e titulos
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumo}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela}
\renewcommand\refname{Referências}

\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}
```

Comment: The ``\\`` is strictly for text lines, you can't use it without text like you can just press Enter in Word. There should be some vertical space before and after `figure`s. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows your exact problem.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I've updated the OP.

Comment: We would need a *complete* example with the preamble. The `figurehere` is not a standard environment. Normal `figure` environments do add vertical space.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: updated again. I'm not sure that's all you're asking?

Comment: No, this is not yet an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Please turn it into a complete compilable, but minimal document (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that we could copy and paste to understand your problem. This would encourage the gurus here to help you.

Comment: @Daniel: I see.

Comment: I don't understand. Why aren't you using the usual `figure` environment? Do you want to avoid floats? Perhaps if you could put your motivation in the question it would help.

Answer (score 8):

If you *really* want your figures and tables here-and-no-discussion-about-it, then you can load the `float` package and use

```
\begin{figure}[H]
...
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
...
\end{table}
```

instead of your `figurehere` and `tablehere` environments (which are defined *not* to leave any vertical space around them). It will be easier to modify the option to get a floating environment (which I recommend).

### Side notes

1. Don't use the `ae` and `aecompl` packages: they are obsolete. Also `subfigure` is obsolete and `subfig` should be used.
2. Usage of `ucs` and the `[utf8x]` option to `inputenc` is probably not needed (and incompatible with packages such as `biblatex`); use simply

   ```
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   ```
3. `hyperref` should be loaded last

Here's an amended version

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{multicol,multirow,graphicx,tabularx}
\usepackage{marvosym,textcomp,cancel,gensymb,pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float} % for the H specifier
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% set up
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\lstset{language=Java, keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},escapechar=|}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok, you seem to want to make your own figure environment. Note that LaTeX doesn't recognize such an environment automatically as a figure and somehow adds vertical space by itself. You need to add it manually using e.g. using `\vspace{<length>}` or `\medskip`/`\bigskip` etc. at the end of the environment. Adding a manual paragraph break using `\par` would also be something to consider.

```
\newenvironment{figurehere}
  {\def\@captype{figure}}
  {\par\medskip}% or \par\vspace{1ex} etc.
```